# Toggle class to specific element depends on hash from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

How toggle class to specific html element if the hash e.g) equal #area & the id="Hafr"

i need to toggle

```
class="opened"
```

to this element

```
<div id="hafr"></div>
```

if the hash from the url = #area

please look for my submenu in jsfiddle! 
http://jsfiddle.net/samehsubscription/8u5qy/

Comment: Can't find class="opened" in your jsfiddle

Comment: `if (window.location.hash == 'area') $('#hafr').addClass('opened')`

Comment: yeah i need just to add it if the user is navigating between pages so if he navigate from main page to sub page that will be in the second level of the sub menu then the submenu will opened if the class= opened look for this example i added it manually !
http://jsfiddle.net/samehsubscription/8u5qy/3/

Comment: @abhitalks thats worked good but small edites to work perefect 
`if (window.location.hash == '#area') $('#hafr').addClass('opened')`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (window.location.hash == '#area') $('#hafr').addClass('opened');
```

Thanx @abhitalks